# Linked List Print() Function Printing Ascii number of Char

Tags: c++, linked-list

I creating  type linked list and taking chars from the user. 
This is the class definition.

```
    template <class nodeT>
struct nodeSLL
{
    int data;                                               //Data inside the node
    nodeSLL* link;                                          //Address next node
};

    char itemC;
```

This is a main()

```
singlyLinkedList<char> listCSLL; //Creating linked list
cout << "Create Char Single Linked List: "
    << "\nCTRL+Z for exit!" << endl;
cin >> itemC;

    while (!cin.eof())
{
    listCSLL.insertLast(itemC);
    cin >> itemC;
}
listCSLL.printSLL();
```

but my print function printing ASCII decimal represent of chars

```
    template <class nodeT>
void singlyLinkedList<nodeT>::printSLL()
{
    nodeSLL<nodeT>* move;
    move = head;
    while (move != NULL)
    {
        cout << move->data << " ";
        move = move->link;
    }
}
```

My program can create int, or char lists, for printing int its ok, but char lists printing ascii decimal format

Comment: Please include the definitions of the classes you're using - the type of `nodeSLL<nodeT>::data` is probably going to be relevant here. In general, you should reduce your problem down to an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it clearer, and in doing so you'll often find the solution yourself.

Comment: is it ok now? @hnefatl

Comment: Instead of `int data;` you should templatize by using `nodeT data;`

Comment: Thank you for helping its working now. @Wander3r I cannot your answer to mark solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of 
`int data;`
You should templatize nodeSLL by changing it to
`nodeT data;` If not, whether passing `int` or `char` or any other datatype still results in printing `int`.

If not, passing the template won't affect the `struct nodeSLL` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
char itemC;  // This is a char
```

You read some input into a `char` & then transfer it into an `int`

```
int data;
```

Which you are printing in the print function

```
 cout << move->data << " ";
```

since data type of `data` is int, it will print it as a number.

If you want a `char`, use `char` at both places. If you want an `int`, use `int` at both places.

Assuming you want a `char`, just change `itemC` to `char`

```
char itemC;
```